# Using CSOM in SharePoint Online Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom

I've recently been playing with apps in SharePoint Online. I've wrote a few basic CRUD apps that use JSOM and the REST APIs. These approaches are relatively well documented online, so finding material/tutorials isn't a problem.

However, I keep reading that we can also use CSOM (C#) in our hosted apps, yet I can't find any decent supporting material. The material that I have found seem to be interacting with SharePoint via CSOM using a console application.

Can this be done in a hosted app too? My .aspx pages do not have a code-behind, so I'm unsure of where the CSOM actually goes in my project?

Have I got the wrong end of the stick entirely, i.e. when people are discussing CSOM in hosted apps are they really referring to JSOM? The acronyms appear to be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the acronym is often used interchangeably, SharePoint hosted apps would require JavaScript CSOM whereas Provider hosted apps can work with the Managed (C#) Client Object Model as well